# How to remove a component using directives in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I need your precious help. I have a component that needs to add another component on a click of a button. In my 'viewunitcomponent' I have a button for each record to view the detail of that record. I call a component to do this and it's in my 'editcomponent'. When I click a button in a table I can get the component just fine but when I click on another record, the 'editcomponent' does not change anymore. I use a directive and an ng-template. Please see my code below.

**viewunit.html**

```
<div class="col-md-9">
    <div *ngIf="showEdit">
      <ng-template myNgIf [value]="showEdit" >
        <app-editunit></app-editunit>
      </ng-template>
    </div>
</div>
```

the `<app-editunit>` is another component that shows where I can actually edit the details of the record selected.

**viewunit.ts**

```
onViewDetail(element) {
    this.showEdit = false;
    this.genParams.unitToEdit = null;
    this.genParams.unitToEdit = element;
    if (this.genParams.unitToEdit !== null || this.genParams.unitToEdit !== undefined) {
      this.showEdit = true;
    }
    console.log(element);
}
```

**myNgIf.directive**

```
@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line:directive-selector
  selector: '[myNgIf]'
})
export class MyNgIfDirective implements OnInit {
  val: boolean;
  @Input() set value(val: boolean) {
    debugger;
    this.val = val;
    this.createOrNot(val);
  }

  constructor(
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private template: TemplateRef<object>
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  public createOrNot(value) {
    debugger;
    const condition = value;

    if (condition) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

**edit.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.unitToEdit = this.genParams.unitToEdit;
    this.createForm();
  }

createForm() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      UnitName: [this.unitToEdit.UnitName],
      InAssmt: [this.unitToEdit.InAssmt],
      InFreqAssmt: [this.unitToEdit.InFreqAssmt],
      InTypeOfAssmt: [this.unitToEdit.InTypeOfAssmt],
      RlPropAssmt: [this.unitToEdit.RlPropAssmt],
      RlFreqAssmt: [this.unitToEdit.RlFreqAssmt],
      RlTypeOfAssmt: [this.unitToEdit.RlTypeOfAssmt],
      AdvAnlPymtScm: [this.unitToEdit.AdvAnlPymtScm],
      DiscRt: [this.unitToEdit.DiscRt],
      DdlnOfAvlmnt: [this.unitToEdit.DdlnOfAvlmnt],
      PenHoldy: [this.unitToEdit.PenHoldy],
      ElecChrg: [this.unitToEdit.ElecChrg],
      ElecTypeOfAssmt: [this.unitToEdit.ElecTypeOfAssmt],
      WtrChrg: [this.unitToEdit.WtrChrg],
      WtrTypeOfAssmt: [this.unitToEdit.WtrTypeOfAssmt],
    });
  }
```

I really need your help. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you think you need a MyNgIf directive for soething like that? What's wrong with NgIf?

Comment: I need to destroy the component so I can recreate it because in the editunit, on the ngInit, I create a formgroup.

Comment: That's not a sufficient reason. Please clarify your question by showing/ explaining how the page should look like, and what should happen when you click somewhere. If the same edit component is used to edit all elements, then use ngOnChanges inside that edit component to know when the edited element changes. That's what it's for. No need to destroy and recreate anything.

Comment: Please see my edited question. My reason for destroying and recreating is because of the ngInit of the editcomponent. I need to change the initial values of the form. But your ngOnChanges is something that I've not explored. Can you please give me a simple example on how I can implement this on using a single component to edit different records?

Comment: Here's a simple example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vgtgar?file=src%2Fapp%2Fedit.component.ts

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH JB Nizet!!!